# Fail to load package dependency at runtime

Tags: .net, nuget-package, transitive-dependency

My solution uses central package management and targets .net6.0 framework and at execution I get the following exception:System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Dependencies look similar to

```
ProjectA -> library -> System.Net.Http.Json 7.0.1 -> System.Text.Json 7.0.2
ProjectB -> (ProjectReference) ProjectA
ProjectB -> Azure.Monitor.Injestion (1.1.1) -> System.Text.Json 7.0.2
```

It is ProjectB execution which throws the exception.

I dont want to downgrade library to hopefully get to 7.0.0 version for System.Text.Json somehow.

I did try to use `<PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" VersionOverride="7.0.0" />` for ProjectB, cant figure it out.

Comment: Did you deploy also the dll in your debug/release folder, they are copied automatically when you compile your program

Comment: my DLLs are present in bin\Debug\net60 folder after the solution compiling.  System.Net.Http.Json.dll , System.Text.Json.dll & Azure.Monitor.Injection.dll are also present.

Comment: you have to check the references https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-references-in-a-project?view=vs-2022  and remove 7.00 and add the version that you use in the debug/release folder

Comment: I dont reference System.Text.Json at all in my solution directly. It is a transitive dependency other libraries I use do reference. I cant see where from should I remove System.Text.Json 7.0.0 version and to what projects do I need to add version from debug folder ? 

Also, my solution uses central package management .

Comment: the nuget installer adds a reference automatically and shold in principle be pto date. you could deinstall the package and reinstall it and if the problem goes a way you can see all refeences in the option of your app

Comment: Do you suggest to manually  remove the reference to package Azure.Monitor.Injestion and add it back ? I did that but no changes.

I dont understand what you're refering to when you say 'you can see all references in the option of you app'; what option?

Comment: no start only with json and see if that works, the rest comes later

Comment: thanks, here is what I did:

add a direct reference to System.Text.Json version 7.0.0 for ProjectB; it does not work as ProjectA uses a more recent version (7.0.2), the error is "Detected package downgrade ..."

add a direct reference to System.Text.Json version 8.0.0 for ProjectB. that should force both ProjectA and Azure.Monitor.Injestion library to use System.Text.Json 8.0.0. However, during execution, I still get : "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version 8.0.0, ...'". System.Text.Json.dll 8.0.0 is correctly copied in \bin\Debug\net6.0 folder. can't explain it ?!?

Comment: A normal windows would first look in the program folder and then look if the system has it. With azure i don't know if of would do, maybe you should take it azure and see if experts can help you

Comment: Debug is done on 'normal Windows', it has nothing to do with Azure (for now).